# AccessControlEnumerable vs AccessControl

Tags: openzeppelin

Is there a best practice on when to choose one or the other? The documentation vaguely discusses on-chain vs off-chain responsibilities.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access